# Searching a value in an aribitrary structure in C

Tags: c, search, structure

If I have a structure like this.

```
[CODE] 
    cogMacframe.header.destAddr = dest;
    cogMacframe.header.cogParam = nextChan;
    cogMacframe.header.somethingIdontknowbutIaminterested = 10;
    cogMacframe.header.somethingIdontknow = xyz; 
[/CODE]
```

Here, if I don't know exactly the fields of the structure but I know that one of the unknown field will take some value lets say 10. I need to search for this value of 10 and get the field from this value.

Can I do this and how ?

I am working in Warpboard which uses C Language .The structure is a Macframe header. This header is received from an unknown node using its own header format so i don't know its fields but I do know that one of the field will take a particular value and I need to search that value and access the field.

Comment: So you want variable name from it's value right? oh...have you tried anything your self?

Comment: It is going to be difficult to pick out `10` in a memory block of `11101001001010`. Do you know the size of each of the struct members or are you just planning on taking the staring address of the struct and doing some type of raw search of memory from then on?

Comment: I think that you need to understand the nature of the data you are dealing with and how it is structured by a close look at the relevant header files.